# How to run the "set a Global Variable" only once in POSTMAN and use them for all the keys In the collection

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-native-app

I have a request body as follows, Here I need the keys "id", "sys2Acct" and "shortName" to be set to a same value.

NOTE: the request body has huge number of key's, I somehow want to assign the same number (i.e random) to the mentioned keys in this request and also for the other requests in the collection.

Currently I have written the following  script in Collection Pre-Request, But the problem is it is being called every time for the keys, hence resulting in different numbers for the keys

Code in collection pre-request script:

```
pm.globals.set("randomNumber", JSON.stringify('{{$randomCreditCardMask}}'));
```

Output:

```
{"id":"0372","name":"AN","contName":"CN","phone":"","sys2Acct":"7491","shortName":"2592"}
```

Can you please guide me how to achieve this.

```
"id":{{randomNumber}},"name":"AN","contName":"CN","phone":"","sys2Acct":{{randomNumber}},"shortName":{{randomNumber}},
```

Comment: Do you mean, for every request you need to generate one single random number and that will then be attributed to `id`, `sys2Acct` and `shortName`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly and you have a body that on each request needs to be sent where 3 parameters have the same random number, you can do this (just one way of doing it)

On your pre-request script generate a `randomInt` with [Postman Dynamic variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/). Then, set the whole payload to a global variable:

```js
const randomInt = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomInt}}')
const payload = {
    "id": randomInt,
    "name":"AN",
    "contName":"CN",
    "phone":"",
    "sys2Acct":randomInt,
    "shortName": randomInt
    }

pm.globals.set("payload", JSON.stringify(payload));
```

Now set the body to the `{{payload}}`

[image]

And you can see that on each request, the body is the the same with the 3 properties you listed set to the same random number. [I've created a public request with this example](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/vitor-s-sandbox/request/19391207-3e7f2bc9-e069-4250-a81b-d6018605e741), so if you hit send and then check the Body response you'll see that the payload works as you described it:

**Request #1**

[image]

**Request #2**

[image]

And so on.

Comment: The problem is, my request headers have many keys and I dont want to pull them all in the script. I just want these keys (id, sys2Acct, shortName) to have same random number assigned. I have edited my question.

Comment: Where do you get the first body from with all the keys? That conditions what the pre-script looks like.

Comment: Then you probably just need to do some object merging with the new .. syntax: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/javascript-merge-objects/

Comment: Yeah the last link helps, Thanks Man :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a folder full of requests that all require the same random number, what I would do is just set the random variable in the pre-request script tab of your first request of the folder (instead of at the collection level), and continue to use the variable in the rest of your requests.